# which module LDAP to be used for NGINX 1.4.2-13

Tags: nginx

I am implementing NGINX module **LDAP** on an NGINX deployment with the following package on Centos:

**nginx-1.4.2-13.el6.art.x86_64** derived from a **C65-Atomic** repo

This is not an NGINX Plus version, so I need to deploy the module LDAP by myself. I am unable to figure out what is the exact branch/version/commit of the LDAP module to be adopted for this nginx version.

My deployment has none of these files:

- nginx-ldap-auth.conf
- nginx-ldap-auth-daemon-ctl.sh

... therefore it seems to confirm the LDAP module is not part of this deployment. The LDAP module git repo is located at:

https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth